# T injective implies T*T invertible?

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose $V$, $W$ are inner product spaces, and $V$ is finite-dimensional. I need to prove that if $T \in \mathcal{L}(M)$ is an injective linear map, and $T^*$ is the adjoint of $T$, then $T^*T$ is invertible.

I got as far as to say that if $T$ is injective, then $T^*$ is surjective. But I don't know how to show that $T^*T$ is invertible. Showing that $T^*T$ is surjective or injective would imply invertibility, but I'm not sure how to do that either. I was hoping to find a way to show that $T^*$ is injective (which would then imply that $T^*T$ is injective) but I wasn't able to.

Comment: What is $M$?  What is the domain and range of $T$?

Comment: $T^*Tx = 0$ implies $\langle Tx, Tx \rangle = \langle T^* Tx,x \rangle = 0$ implies $Tx = 0$ implies $x = 0$. So, $T^*T$ injective.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Show that $T^*Tx = 0$ implies that $Tx = 0$, which means that $T^*T$ is also injective.